# XSLT use first child node value in later child nodes

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transform

I got a HTML file to transform into a XML file using XSLT, where I need to grab only the first child node's date value to be used in the latter child nodes, since the latter child nodes do not have the data values and the tags will appear empty. I tried to use positioning to do that for the XSLT but to no avail.

The relevant HTML code is:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="8" scope="rowgroup">2005DEC</th>  
    <th scope="row">Blemish on Card</th>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Damaged</th>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th rowspan="8" scope="rowgroup">2006JAN</th>  
    <th scope="row">Lost</th>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Stolen</th>

  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The relevant XSLT code is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr">
    <Entry>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="th[@scope='rowgroup']">
                <Year>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(th[@scope='rowgroup']/., 1, 4)" />
                </Year>
                <Month>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(th[@scope='rowgroup']/., 5, 3)" />
                </Month>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Year>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(tr[1]/th[@scope='rowgroup']/., 1, 4)" />
                </Year>
                <Month>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(tr[1]/th[@scope='rowgroup']/., 5, 3)" />
                </Month>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Entry>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The XML code that is output is the following, which is not what I want as the second child node does not have the date value of the first child node and just shows up as an empty value tag for year and month:

```
<Entry>
  <Year>2005</Year>
  <Month>DEC</Month>
  <Reason>Blemish on Card</Reason>
</Entry>
<Entry>
  <Year/>
  <Month/>
  <Reason>Damaged</Reason>
</Entry>
<Entry>
  <Year>2006</Year>
  <Month>JAN</Month>
  <Reason>Lost</Reason>
</Entry>
<Entry>
  <Year/>
  <Month/>
  <Reason>Stolen</Reason>
</Entry>
```

What I need is:

```
<Entry>
  <Year>2005</Year>
  <Month>DEC</Month>
  <Reason>Blemish on Card</Reason>
</Entry>
<Entry>
  <Year>2005</Year>
  <Month>DEC</Month>
  <Reason>Damaged</Reason>
</Entry>
<Entry>
  <Year>2006</Year>
  <Month>JAN</Month>
  <Reason>Lost</Reason>
</Entry>
<Entry>
  <Year>2006</Year>
  <Month>JAN</Month>
  <Reason>Stolen</Reason>
</Entry>
```

How do I do that for my XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to navigate up first: `substring(../tr[1]/th[@scope='rowgroup']/., 1, 4)`  if you want to select the data from the first row.

Based on your comments that is not what you want, if you want to select the data from the first preceding sibling row with a `scope="rowgroup"` attribute then one way, continuing with your approach is

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tbody/tr">
    <Entry>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="th[@scope='rowgroup']">
                <Year>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(th[@scope='rowgroup']/., 1, 4)" />
                </Year>
                <Month>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(th[@scope='rowgroup']/., 5, 3)" />
                </Month>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Year>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(preceding-sibling::tr[th[@scope='rowgroup']][1]/th[@scope='rowgroup'], 1, 4)" />
                </Year>
                <Month>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(preceding-sibling::tr[th[@scope='rowgroup']][1]/th[@scope='rowgroup'], 5, 3)" />
                </Month>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:for-each select="th[@scope='row']">
            <Reason>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </Reason>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Entry>
</xsl:for-each>
```

although I might be easier to use `for-each-group group-starting-with="tr[th[@scope = 'rowgroup']]"` if you use an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: That works but it will affect the foreach. Coz the foreach targets multiple time periods, but now although the latter child nodes in each foreach capture the first child node's values, but they only use the first child node's values from the first foreach.

Comment: You have only shown a single table and a single for-each so I am afraid I can't tell what your comment relates to. If the problem is not solved then edit the question and show the necessary details of the input, XSLT you have and output you want and the one you get.

Comment: Does using `substring(../preceding-sibling::tr[@scope='rowgroup'][1]/th[@scope='rowgroup']/., 1, 4)` give you the result you want? I am currently not sure how you want to identify the row with the relevant value.

Comment: Error at xsl:value-of on line 29 column 126 of table826.xslt:
  XPST0003 XPath syntax error at char 62 on line 29 near {...ope='rowgroup'][1]/th[\u200...}:
    Invalid QName {\u200c\u200b}
Error at xsl:value-of on line 32 column 126 of table826.xslt:
  XPST0003 XPath syntax error at char 62 on line 32 near {...ope='rowgroup'][1]/th[\u200...}:
    Invalid QName {\u200c\u200b}
Failed to compile stylesheet. 2 errors detected.

Comment: I have given a larger snippet with my suggestion, see if that captures the requirement you have.

Comment: Thanks the answer is correct for what I want for the date! I missed out having the reason in the original code - your reason code should be the following answer instead, then it will be perfect, but yeah the main trouble I had was with the date in the child nodes, and not the reason, so yeah thanks! =)

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="th[@scope='row']">
<Reason>
 <xsl:value-of select="." />
</Reason></xsl:for-each>